# How to track touch actions on screen during test automation with Appium

Tags: android, ios, ruby, automated-tests, appium

I am using appium to run automated tests for a mobile app. the app is on both android and ios and my tests are written in ruby.

In my test code, I tap specific coordinates on the screen however I am not able to verify that the correct position was tapped if no action resulted from the tap.

What I would like is some kinda of visual cue so that I can tell where on the screen was tapped, pressed, swiped, etc. Is there any way to do with appium?

On android, in the settings under developer options I can select "show taps" which will temporarily display a circle where I tap on the screen but this doesn't seem to work while running tests. I'd like to know if there are any ways to do this on either android or ios. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I can tell you with certainty that Appium does not have capabilities for this. However, I can give you a tip for debugging: put the tap command multiple times (sometimes the first tap does not work - I've experienced this), log the width and height of the app (to make sure it's not displayed in landscape when it should be portrait and vice versa), and try multiple methods of tapping - element.tap and actions library tap (long press, etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Android you should enable `Show touches` and `Pointer location` too from developer option, It will show the pointer location of `Click/Swipe/Tap`. It's working fine for me during automation.

Comment: I just found the pointer location option myself. it was very helpful. iOS does not seem to have a reliable method however.

Comment: @Akil I recently experienced an iOS device and I share your opinion about iOS. iOS exposes Gestures with Assistive Touch. I tested it and it too complicated and gives a lot of overhead if you want to show all touches you do on an app like on Android. I don't know why Apple complicates a very easy thing offered by Android